# Oracle datapump import into new 10.2.0.5 database

Tags: oracle, import, oracle10g, database-administration, datapump

We are currently migrating to a brand new server/Oracle DB in order to upgrade our memory (RAM). In order to populate this database we have decided to use the Oracle Data Pump functionality and creating the flat export file completed without error.

However, when importing this in the new DB it is returning the following errors:

```
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/JAVA_SOURCE/JAVA_SOURCE
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/JAVA_CLASS/JAVA_CLASS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/STATISTICS/FUNCTIONAL_AND_BITMAP/INDEX_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/STATISTICS/TABLE_STATISTICS
Processing object type DATABASE_EXPORT/SCHEMA/TABLE/INDEX/DOMAIN_INDEX/INDEX
ORA-39083: Object type INDEX failed to create with error:
ORA-29855: error occurred in the execution of ODCIINDEXCREATE routine
ORA-20000: Oracle Text error:
DRG-50857: oracle error in drueixe
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 40 bytes (kxs-heap-f,frame segment)
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRVUTL", line 17
ORA-06512: at "CTXSYS.DRVXMD", line 199
ORA-06512: at line 1


Failing sql is:
CREATE INDEX "SCHOWN"."CUSTOMER_ORDER_TIX" ON "SCHOWN"."CUSTOMER_ORDER_TAB" ("TEXT_ID$")  INDEXTYPE IS "CT
ORA-39125: Worker unexpected fatal error in KUPW$WORKER.PUT_DDLS while calling DBMS_METADATA.CONVERT [INDEX:"SCHOWN"."TERM_TIX"]
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
LPX-00210: expected '<' instead of 'ÿ'
ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 4194328 bytes (pga heap,buf_kgcstate)
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.KUPW$WORKER", line 6377
----- PL/SQL Call Stack -----
  object      line  object
  handle    number  name
0000001ECACBEE08     15370  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001ECACBEE08      6436  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001ECACBEE08     12590  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001ECACBEE08      3397  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001ECACBEE08      7064  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001ECACBEE08      1340  package body SYS.KUPW$WORKER
0000001EA04A22C0         2  anonymous block
Job "SYS"."SYS_IMPORT_SCHEMA_03" stopped due to fatal error at 18:40:14
```

I will update this question with the exact import syntax used as soon as possible. UPDATE:

```
impdp “/ as sysdba” dumpfile=staging_full.dmp schemas=SCHOWN directory=exp logfile=import_schown3.log
```

Any guidance would be extremely helpful?

Answer (score 0):

The key error message here is this one:

> ORA-04030: out of process memory when trying to allocate 4194328 bytes (pga heap,buf_kgcstate)

The database does not have enough memory to complete the import. This isn't related to the amount of RAM on the box, but the amount of RAM that has been specifically allocated to Oracle. This is controlled by the memory_target parameter in Oracle 11g.

What version of Oracle are you running? There is a known bug regarding the import of statistics in version 11.2 detailed here:

http://santoshnm.wordpress.com/2013/12/03/ora-04030-out-of-memory-during-import-datapump-impdp/

It seems likely to me that you are hitting this problem. The workaround is to exclude the statistics and gather them again after the import. Try adding

> EXCLUDE=STATISTICS

to your parameter file, and it will probably work.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, this is a 10.2g database. We thought that this was the case and therefore increased the 'pga_aggregate_target' from 5GB to 32GB - the same errors occurred?

Comment: Oh sorry I missed the version in the title. Try excluding the statistics, bugs can often be reported in one version but occur and reoccur in many versions.